# How to make a Python library work on Spark YARN

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

If I want to use a python library for a specific task, like NLTK or BeautifulSoup I can do that when I use Spark on my local machine, but the same thing doesn't work with Spark on YARN.

Here is a sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

def html_parsing(x):
    """ Cleans the text from Data Frame text column"""

    textcleaned=''
    #if row['desc'] is not None: 
    souptext=BeautifulSoup(x)
    #souptext=BeautifulSoup(text)
    p_tags=souptext.find_all('p')
    for p in p_tags: 
        if p.string:
            textcleaned+=p.string
    #print textcleaned
    #ret_list= (int(row['id']),row['title'],textcleaned)

    return textcleaned


parse_html=udf(html_parsing,StringType())

sdf_cleaned=sdf_rss.dropna(subset=['desc']).withColumn('text_cleaned',parse_html('desc'))\
.select('id','title','text_cleaned')

sdf_cleaned.cache().take(3)
```

This code works on my local Spark and cleans the Html tags. However, when I run it on Spark on YARN, it doesn't work and says the following:

```
  File "/var/storage/nm-sdl1/nm-local/usercache/appcache/application_1485803993783_0664/container_1485803993783_0664_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named bs4

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:124)
```

All these packages are installed on my Anaconda installed on cluster. However I guess the problem might be that this package is not available on executors. My hunch.

Any idea how we can make any python package work on Spark on YARN?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to point the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable to point to your anaconda path.

By default, Spark will look for the first python executable it finds in the path. Typically, that will be the system installation of python (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`). For pyspark to know where your anaconda distribution is installed, you need to set the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable. For example, execute `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/anaconda/bin/python` before running your python script or running `pyspark`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit in detail? I am not sure I got that. I have the library installed in anaconda. But if I use that on Spark on Yarn, i dont think that library is available to executors. So how do I make that available so that it can work on executors and on the RDD block there? I guess that is what causing it to say "No module bs4"

Comment: Well Pyspark uses Anaconda python only. Pyspark shell uses that and I can see that. Its set in my bash profile too

Comment: Try running the following, which should tell you which executable you're using: `spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(100), 10).map(lambda x: sys.executable).distinct().collect()`